# Can't get nouveau to work with VA_API for video acceleration on firefox? Only can get CPU drivers to work with firefox

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu-driver, hardware-acceleration, vaapi

Edit2: Sorry, running Ubuntu **20.04.3 LTS, and HWE stack.** I get the same error with the GA Stack.

_

I've been trying to get nouveau to work so that I can use my Nvidia P500 for hardware acceleration instead of my CPU.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
(base) wallheck@wallheck:~$ export LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=nouveau
(base) wallheck@wallheck:~$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 1.7.0
libva info: User environment variable requested driver 'nouveau'
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_7
iris: driver missing
iris: driver missing
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 2
vaInitialize failed with error code 2 (resource allocation failed),exit
```

I installed nouveau with

```
sudo apt install nouveau-firmware
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

and for both it says its already the newest version.

I am able to get video acceleration to work with the CPU using this guide: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hardware-video-acceleration-va-api-for-firefox-in-ubuntu-20-04-18-04-higher/.
Using i965 drivers, I get activity under the video row when I use `sudo intel_gpu_top`.

However, when I use `nvtop`, I cannot get any activity for my GPU.

Here's the kernel drivers for the integrated graphics and GPU:

```
(base) wallheck@wallheck:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo UHD Graphics 620
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108GLM [Quadro P500 Mobile] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GP108GLM [Quadro P500 Mobile]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

I don't think I need to change the kernel driver to nouveau as the intel drivers worked with i965 specified and i915 kernel in use.

Not really sure what to do from here.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, being a LTS has two stack choices.  If you use a `uname -r` you'll see a 5.4 kernel in use if you're using the GA (ie. more *stable* choice) kernel stack, and a 5.11 using the HWE stack (at 20.04.3). You can have both stacks installed (selecting which you use at boot (ie. `grub`) where one stack may have more choices than the alternative (as they'll use different kernel modules (ie. *drivers*), but it still may not offer what you're seeking - but may still help. You haven't specified which stack you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the following is probably not the desired solution by the OP. But I would look at the whole thing from a somewhat different perspective.

At first, so far I know the VA-API support is (still) [not fully mature](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/VideoAcceleration.html) in the `nouveau` driver. Only VDPAU is avaiable as the reliable solution but that one cannot be used in Firefox (and under Wayland).

However, why must the video decoding be processed via the Nvidia GPU when an Intel iGPU which includes the **Intel Quick Sync Video** functionality is present? I think that should be here the way to go.
In my case `DRI_PRIME=0 firefox` starts firefox at `GPU 0` while `DRI_PRIME=1 firefox` will start it at `GPU 1`.

The problem is that this principle doesn't work with the classic `i965` driver, it only works with "normal" **Gallium3D** based drivers. Here will be the new `crocus` driver an option, it is for sure compatible with nouveau (which is itself Gallium based). Unfortunately `crocus` lacks at the moment any VA-API support, that one should be added during the next months. Note, that new driver can be tested via the **Oibaf PPA**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally, if any attempt to use the **Intel Quick Sync Video** feature via the `i965` driver is failing I see only one last workaround. The NVIDIA GPU has to be disabled temporary in the Lenovo firmware. This will then effectively disable the `nouveau` driver and everything will fall back to the `i965` classic one. I know this sucks but this will allow VA-API video decoding via **Intel Quick Sync Video** in Firefox. And when `crocus` is finished, the switching between the GPU and their capabilities should be no longer a problem. ;-)